# BrowserMob Proxy returning empty HTML response with Chrome headless browser, how can this be resolved?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, proxy, google-chrome-headless, browsermob-proxy

I am trying to use BrowsermobProxy to Sniff network logs from my UI automation tests. I have to implement it for both **HEAD** and **HEADLESS** *RemoteDriver*. For Head-Driver it is working like a charm.

Code for my Head-Remote Driver:

```java
Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(browserMobProxy);
        seleniumProxy.setNoProxy("<-loopback>");
        seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy("localhost" + ":" + browserMobProxy.getPort());
        seleniumProxy.setSslProxy("localhost" + ":" + browserMobProxy.getPort());

desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
                desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, Boolean.TRUE);
                desiredCapabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(Boolean.TRUE);
                desiredCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
ChromeOptions options = getChromeOptions(driverConfig.getUserAgent(), Boolean.TRUE);
                options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
                desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

return RemoteWebDriver(remoteAddress, desiredCapabilities)
```

For Headless-RemoteDriver code:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--user-agent=" + "HeadlessChrome");
        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(Boolean.TRUE);
        options.setHeadless(true);
        options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-extensions", "--window-size=1920,1080");
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
List<String> optionsArg = ImmutableList.of("--ignore-certificate-errors", "--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>",
                        "--proxy-server=http://localhost:" + mobProxy.getPort(), "--remote-debugging-port=9222");
                options.addArguments("--ssl-protocol=any");
                options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
                options.addArguments(optionsArg);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(driverUrl, capabilities);
```

In case of my headless driver the config for driver are as follows:

**Driver URL** -> http://localhost:<port_number> *[eg: http://localhost:29515]*

**BrowserMob Proxy Port** -> <dynamic_port> *[eg:33173]*

**Proxy Server Address** -> http://localhost:<dynamic_port> *[eg: http://localhost:33173]*

The full capabilities list before driver creation for headless is as follows:

```java
{acceptInsecureCerts=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=chrome, 
goog:chromeOptions={args=[--user-agent=HeadlessChrome, --headless, --disable-gpu, 
--allow-insecure-localhost, --no-sandbox, --disable-extensions, 
--window-size=1920,1080, --ssl-protocol=any, --allow-running-insecure-content, 
--ignore-certificate-errors, --proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>, 
--proxy-server=http://localhost:33173, --remote-debugging-port=9222], extensions=[]},
 platform=ANY, version=}
```

**Result**

When taken screenshot I am seeing a white page only on test failure, Implicit waits are already applies for page load and on top of that I have tried with 5 seconds static sleep time. No fix. I get a HTML dump:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

**NOTES**

1. I have tried with the argument **--proxy-bypass-list=***, but in this case the network is not routed through mob proxy, as I am unable to record any logs. The pages are loading fine in this case.
2. The capabilities: --ssl-protocol=any, --remote-debugging-port=9222 and --allow-running-insecure-content are extras, I have tried without them also, no avail.
3. I am using browser-mob-proxy = 2.1.5
4. ChromeDriver version = 92.0.4515.159
5. I am running this on a **Remote Linux CLI System**
6. When starting the browsermob proxy I am doing the following:

```java
System.setProperty("bmp.allowNativeDnsFallback", "true");
        BrowserMobProxy browserMobProxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        browserMobProxy.setTrustAllServers(Boolean.TRUE);
```

**Kindly, someone help to resolve this issue, I am stuck for at least a week now and my deadline is nearing fast.**

Comment: why are you using different ways to specify proxy for your browser in regular and in headless modes? Also what if you capture har and analyze that? Does your page load any resources?

Comment: In Headless the WebDriver was not recognizing the selenium Proxy Instance so  I had to provide as part of Chrome Options @AlexeyR.

Comment: The strange part is the same code was running fine a month back, I came back to the code after 1 month and it stopped working

Answer (score 0):

```
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
```

For headless chrome , useragent is set as chromeheadless or something , this makes website to detect that you are using headless chrome and behave differently

You can vent this by specifying hardcoded useragent,

open a normal chrome , goto network tab , open request header and copy the user agent part and replace in your code

Comment: Does the useragent need to be same as the chromedriver version, like 92.02..., or anyone will do? And what if the `--user-agent=null` is given ?

Comment: @DipanBiswas copy it from browser network tab , give proper one as website uses this to identify what brwoser or device we use

Comment: No avail, I tried with User Agent as: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 .. Same Error